# Pytorch: Learnable threshold for clipping activations

Tags: pytorch

What is the proper way to clip ReLU activations with a learnable threshold? Here's how I implemented it, however I'm not sure if this is correct:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.act_max = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([0]), requires_grad=True)

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(64 * 5 * 5, 10)

    def forward(self, input):
        conv1 = self.conv1(input)
        pool1 = self.pool(conv1)
        relu1 = self.relu(pool1)

        relu1[relu1 > self.act_max] = self.act_max

        conv2 = self.conv2(relu1)
        pool2 = self.pool(conv2)
        relu2 = self.relu(pool2)
        relu2 = relu2.view(relu2.size(0), -1)
        linear = self.linear(relu2)
        return linear


model = Net()
torch.nn.init.kaiming_normal_(model.parameters)
nn.init.constant(model.act_max, 1.0)
model = model.cuda()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
for epoch in range(100):
    for i in range(1000):
        output = model(input)
        loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(output, label)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        model.act_max.data = model.act_max.data - 0.001 * model.act_max.grad.data
```

I had to add the last line because without it the value would not update for some reason.

UPDATE: I am now trying a method to compute the uppper bound (act_max) based on the gradients for activations:

1. For all activations above the threshold (relu1[relu1 > self.act_max]), look at their gradients: compute the average direction all these gradients point to.
2. For all positive activations below the threshold, compute the average gradient of which direction they want to change to.
3. The sum of these average gradients determines the direction and magnitude of the change for act_max.

Comment: have you made a better version? I do not think anyone would mind if you are answering your own question and mention the other answer. Unfortunately the clipping as not yet been implemented in pytorch :/

Comment: @MarineGalantin I used torch.where method as suggested by Jatenantaki, and I applied L2 penalty to the sum of the thresholds from all layers, to balance their growth. If you search for "train_act_max" in https://github.com/michaelklachko/NoisyNet/blob/master/noisynet.py you can trace the steps.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with that code.

1. The implementation-level one is that you're using an in-place operation which generally doesn't work well with autograd. Instead of

`relu1[relu1 > self.act_max] = self.act_max`

you should use an out-of-place operation like

`relu1 = torch.where(relu1 > self.act_max, self.act_max, relu1)`

2. The other is more general : neural networks are generally trained with gradient descent methods and threshold values can have no gradient - the loss function is not differentiable with respect to thresholds.

In your model you're using a dirty hackaround (whether you write is as it is or use `torch.where`) - `model.act_max.grad.data` is only defined because for some elements their value is set to `model.act_max`. But this gradient knows nothing about *why* they were set to that value. To make things more concrete, lets define cutoff operation `C(x, t)` which defines whether `x` is above or below threshold `t`

`C(x, t) = 1 if x < t else 0`

and write your clipping operation as a product

`clip(x, t) = C(x, t) * x + (1 - C(x, t)) * t`

you can then see that the threshold `t` has twofold meaning: it controls when to cutoff (inside `C`) and it controls the value above cutoff (the trailing `t`). We can therefore generalize the operation as

`clip(x, t1, t2) = C(x, t1) * x + (1 - C(x, t1)) * t2`

The problem with your operation is that it is only differentiable with respect to `t2` but not `t1`. Your solution ties the two together so that `t1 == t2`, but it is still the case that gradient descent will act as if there was no changing the threshold, only changing the above-the-threshold-value.

For this reason, in general your thresholding operation may not be learning the value you would hope it learns. This is something to keep in mind when developing your operations, but not a *guarantee* of failure - in fact, if you consider the standard `ReLU` on biased output of some linear unit, we get a similar picture. We define the cutoff operation `H`

`H(x, t) = 1 if x > t else 0`

and `ReLU` as

`ReLU(x + b, t) = (x + b) * H(x + b, t) = (x + b) * H(x, t - b)`

where we could again generalize to

`ReLU(x, b, t) = (x + b) * H(x, t)`

and again we can only *learn* `b` and `t` is implicitly following `b`. Yet it seems to work :)

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for not acknowledging your answer sooner. Busy week. I'm confused by your last sentence - what seems to work? We are not learning t  in the ReLU function - it's hardwired to zero.  How is this similar?

Comment: If you consider `ReLU` alone, the cutoff is hardwired to zero. If you consider a `ReLU` following any layer with bias (such as `Linear`), you have the picture above: the "raw" output `x`, the biased output `x + b` and the threshold `t`. `t` is hardwired to 0 with respect to `x + b` but with respect to the raw output, it is just `b == -t`, but in principle any `t` is allowed. The higher `b` is the smaller values of `x` will make it through the `ReLU` without being zeroed-out. "It seems to work" because most CNNs have this `b == -t` constraint and perform well.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. However, in your example, there are multiple values of b per layer (for the convolutional layer, each feature map would have a different bias), and I would like to learn a single threshold per layer. I am now trying to test a method which tries to push the threshold depending on the average direction all activations want to change along (see the update in my question)

Comment: Actually I just tried torch.where method, and it does not update the value either. The gradients are being calculated, but I still need to update the value them manually, just like with my method. Does it work for you?